# RSync creates empty folders

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, rsync

I have following directories. My goal is to compare `OLD` vs `NEW` directory and save the different files in the `DEST` directory:

```
OLD/
...src/
...src/config.js
...test/
...test/main.js  


NEW/
...src/
...src/config.js
...test/
...test/main.js   //Modified

DEST/
//Empty
```

Now for a test I modified the test/main.js in NEW for example. Now when I run:

```
rsync -rvcim --delete --compare-dest=../NEW/ OLD/ DEST/
```

I get following log output:

```
building file list ... done
>fcsT....... test/main.js
```

Great!  It only finds the main.js file which is different, because of the checksum and it sends it!

But actually it also copies and empty src folder making the final directory structure look like this:

```
DEST/
...src/    //Shouldn't be copied
...test/
...test/main.js
```

I don't want the src directory, I only want the changes (Tested it with a bigger project and even though it doesn't show the folders in the log, it copies all folders to the `DEST` folder)

Comment: Can you confirm that you actually have `-m` in the list of options that you use, please?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes that's correct I use rvcim and also tested without -m

Comment: I duplicated your setup in a small experiment and could reproduce the behavior you report using the exact same command with Rsync v3.2.3. However that occurs ONLY if I created `config.js` in `./NEW/src/` and in `./OLD/src/` with same content but separately.  If instead you clobber `./NEW/src/config.js` with its old version in `./OLD/src/config.js` by **copying** it, the empty directory `src/`does not show up in `./DEST`.